# Taylor's Theorem and natural logarithmic inequality

Tags: limits, inequality, taylor-expansion

Use Taylor's theorem to prove that, for $x>0$.
$$
\ln x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^{2}}<\ln (x+1)<\ln x+\frac{1}{x}
$$

The RHS is indeed obvious: algebraic manipulations yield to show $e^{\frac{1}{x}} > 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ which is clear from the first-degree Taylor polynomial of $e^x$ around $x_{0} = 0$. However, after several substitutions, algebraic approaches, and Taylor expansions, similar results for the LHS could not be resolved. Are there alternative ideas to come up for the left-part?

Comment: Can you atleast prove that for $x\gt 1$, $\ln(1+1/x) \gt \frac 1x -\frac{1}{2x^2}$?

Comment: Your attempts didn't work because it's not true. Take e.g $x=1$.

Comment: @K.defaoite It is true for all $x$.

Comment: Actually nevermind, my computer was computing $\log_{10}$ for some odd reason. Apologies.

Comment: @Tavish In fact, I also substituted the original inequality with your written expression; however, as I mentioned, all my attempts are in vain. Would be very appreciated if you could show detailedly how this is true!

Comment: $\ln(1+1/x) = \frac 1x - \frac{1}{2x^2} + R$ where I’m pretty sure $R\gt 0$. I don’t know how to prove that, though. For $0\lt x\lt 1$, just consider the maximum value of $\frac 1x -\frac {1}{2x^2} $ and the minimum value of $\ln(1+1/x)$.

Comment: @Tavish "Pretty sure" is something obscure in mathematics. Strong proof is needed

Comment: @Snowflake It’s not obscure. Being ‘pretty sure’ carries value. As I said, I don’t know a proof. But I tell you that it is true.

Comment: Hint: $$
\log (1 + y) = y - y^2 \int_0^1 {\frac{t}{{1 + yt}}dt} 
$$ for any $y>0$.

Comment: @Gary, good hint, I like it so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taylor’s expansion of the function $\;\ln(1+z)\;$ at $\;z=0\;$ is

$\ln(1+z)=z-\dfrac{z^2}2+\dfrac{z^3}3-\dfrac{z^4}4+\ldots+(-1)^n\dfrac{z^n}n+\ldots$

for all $\;z\in\big]-1,1\big]\;.$

Hence,

$z-\dfrac{z^2}2<\ln(1+z)\quad$ for all $\;z>0\;\land\;z\leqslant1\;.$

By letting $\;z=\dfrac1x\;,\;$ it follows that

$\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{2x^2}<\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)\quad$ for all $\;x\geqslant1\;,$

$\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{2x^2}<\ln\left(\dfrac{x+1}x\right)\quad$ for all $\;x\geqslant1\;,$

$\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{2x^2}<\ln(x+1)-\ln x\quad$ for all $\;x\geqslant1\;,$

$\color{blue}{\ln x+\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{2x^2}<\ln(x+1)\quad\text{ for all }\;x\geqslant1}\;.$

For all $\;x\in\big]0,1\big[\;,\;$ it results that

$\ln x+\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{2x^2}<\ln x+\dfrac12\left[1-\left(\dfrac1x-1\right)^2\right]<$

$<\ln x+\dfrac12<\ln x+\ln2<\ln(2x)<\ln(x+1)\;\;.$

Hence,

$\color{blue}{\ln x+\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{2x^2}<\ln(x+1)\quad\text{ for all }\;x\in\big]0,1\big[}\;.$

Since the Taylor’s expansion of the function $\;e^z\;$ at $\;z=0\;$ is

$e^z=1+z+\dfrac{z^2}{2!}+\dfrac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots+\dfrac{z^n}{n!}+\ldots\;$ for all $\;z\in\mathbb{R}\;\;,$

it follows that

$1+z<e^z\quad$ for all $\;z>0\;,$

$\ln(1+z)<z\quad$ for all $\;z>0\;.$

By letting $\;z=\dfrac1x\;,\;$ we get that

$\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)<\dfrac1x\quad$ for all $\;x>0\;,$

$\ln\left(\dfrac{x+1}x\right)<\dfrac1x\quad$ for all $\;x>0\;,$

$\ln(x+1)-\ln x<\dfrac1x\quad$ for all $\;x>0\;,$

$\color{blue}{\ln(x+1)<\ln x+\dfrac1x\quad\text {for all }\;x>0}\;.$

So far we have proved that

$\color{blue}{\ln x+\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{2x^2}<\ln(x+1)<\ln x+\dfrac1x\quad\text{ for all }\;x>0}\;.$

---

---

---

**Addendum :**

Gary proved that

$\displaystyle\ln(1+y)=y-y^2\int_0^1\!\dfrac t{1+yt}\,\mathrm{d}t\quad$ for all $\;y>0\;.$

Since $\displaystyle\;0<\int_0^1\!\dfrac t{1+yt}\,\mathrm{d}t<\int_0^1\!t\,\mathrm{d}t=\dfrac12\quad$ for all$\;y>0\;,\;$

it follows that

$y-\dfrac{y^2}2<\ln(1+y)<y\quad$ for all $\;y>0\;.$

Comment: Do you have any comments for the remaining case?

Comment: Now, my answer is complete.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the Taylor theorem with the reminder written in Lagrange form.

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(\xi)}{6}(x-a)^3$$

for some $\xi\in(a,x)$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which function do you apply Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: ...on the $\ln(1+x)$, as you have done, then $x\to 1/x$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:(-1,\infty)$ be the function given by $f(y)=\ln (1+y)$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y) &= \ln(1+y)\ ,&f(0)&=0\ ,\\
f'(y) &= \frac 1{1+y}\ ,&f'(0)&=1\ ,\\
f''(y) &= -\frac 1{(1+y)^2}\ ,&f''(0)&=-1\ ,\\
f'''(y) &= +\frac 2{(1+y)^3}>0\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and we apply the Taylor formula with remainder,
[the Taylor formula with remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)
around $0$ for the point $y=1/x$ for the given $x>0$.
We obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\ln(1+x)-\ln x
&=\ln\left(1+\frac 1x\right)\\
&=\ln(1+y)
\\
&=f(y)
\\
&=f(0)+\frac 1{1!}f'(0)\;y+\frac 1{2!}f''(0)\;y^2+\frac 1{3!}\underbrace{f'''(\xi)}_{>0}\;\underbrace{y^3}_{>0}
\\
&\qquad\text{ (for some intermediate point $\xi$ between $0$ and $y$)}
\\
&>f(0)+\frac 1{1!}f'(0)\;y+\frac 1{2!}f''(0)\;y^2
\\
&=0+y-\frac 12y^2
\\
&=0+\frac 1x-\frac 1{2x^2}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$